# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip' python

Tags: python, arrays, input, split, int

I am writing a python program that takes in user input for an int array that is later sorted. I have successfully compiled my program on my machine, however, cannot get it to compile correctly on a Unix server. The Python compiler on my machine is version 3 while I believe the server may be running on Python 2.6. I'm not sure what is the underlying issue.

```
list = input('Enter numbers in array with commas: ').rstrip() #this line is being flagged
list = list.split(',')
print(list)
```

My error:

```
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using Python2, in which `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. So you are actually evaluating your input (which I suppose is something like `1, 2`) to be a tuple - which has no `rstrip` attribute.

Fix your code by using `raw_input` instead of `input`. This will give you a string which you can use `rstrip` on.

I'd also suggest that you use another variable name in place of `list` because you will shadow the built in list.